# how to get variable name as value where it finds match in r

Tags: r

I have a vector in r

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,3,4,5)
c <- c(5,6,7,8)
d <- c(10,11)
```

I have a following dataframe in r.

```
No
1
2
3
4
5
6 
7
8
10
11
```

My desired dataframe is following

```
No     Match
1       a
2       a
3       a
4       a  
5       b
6       c
7       c
8       c
10      d
11      d
```

How can I do it in r?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match` after constructing a table. It will be easy if your vectors are in a list to start:

```
vec_list = list(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d)
x = data.frame(value = unlist(vec_list), letter = rep(names(vec_list), lengths(vec_list)))

# or a named vector
xx = unlist(vec_list)
names(xx) = rep(names(vec_list), lengths(vec_list))


your_data = data.frame(No = 1:8)
your_data$Match = x$letter[match(your_data$No, x$value)]
your_data$Match_vec = names(xx)[match(your_data$No, xx)]
your_data
#    No Match Match_vec
# 1  1     a         a
# 2  2     a         a
# 3  3     a         a
# 4  4     a         a
# 5  5     b         b
# 6  6     c         c
# 7  7     c         c
# 8  8     c         c
```

We could also just de-dupe the `x` table for more-or-less the same result

```
x[!duplicated(x$value), ]
```

Without context it's difficult to know which is best in your situation.

Comment: how can we use it without converting it into dataframe? I have vectors with varying lengths

Comment: I do not want `a,b,c,d` to be converted into data frame. Can we not keep it as vectors and match the same?

Comment: Make a named vector and just match would do it.

Comment: Keeping them as separate vectors - I can't think of a good way. F. Privé is right, you could use a named vector instead of a data frame (see edits).

Answer (score 0):

I have created two functions that can help you get the right variable names. Here's my solution.

```
getVariable <- function(x){
  for(currentVar in ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)){
    if(class(get(currentVar)) == "numeric") if(x %in% get(currentVar)) return(currentVar)
  }
  return(NA)
}

getAll <- function(y){
  myList <- c()
  for(values in y){
    myList <- c(myList,getVariable(values))
  }
  return(myList)
}
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(2,3,4,5)
c <- c(5,6,7,8)
d <- c(10,11)
myDat <- structure(list(No = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L
)), .Names = "No", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
myDat$Match <- getAll(myDat$No)
myDat
# No Match
# 1   1     a
# 2   2     a
# 3   3     a
# 4   4     a
# 5   5     b
# 6   6     c
# 7   7     c
# 8   8     c
# 9  10     d
# 10 11     d
```